# Is there any way to get recipient email in all email templates in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to access recipient email in all email templates,

PS : I tried adding customer.email variable in footer but it doesn't work for all email templates like newsletter, etc.

Comment: What actually do you want? Need more description in question.

Comment: Hi Agilox, actually I want a unsubscribe link in all email templates but this variable {{var subscriber.getUnsubscriptionLink()}} is not accessible in all scopes like new signup email, order email so I was planning to have a custom link which will do custom unsubscribe, but for that I needed recipient email or id from newsletter table in all email templates.